# Extract last value from key value pair using regex

Tags: regex, pcre

Here is sample text-

```
display_errors = On
display_errors= Off
display_errors = On
```

I would like to extract the value of last `display_errors`. How do I do that?

So far, I've `display_errors =(?!.*display_errors = )` which is able to match `display_errors =` but I want its value, not the key.

I am using libpcre for matching with . matches all option

Please note I've to use regex and not any .ini parsing library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
display_errors\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z]+)(?!.*display_errors\s*=)
```

That should match the last value for the `display_errors` key, assuming the values are characters `a-z` (but the accepting-character list can easily be updated if needed).

Comment: How do I make your regex agnostic of space between "display_errors" and "=" ? For example, display_errors=  On

Comment: @user837208 No problem! Glad it works =] .. You can use the `\s*` between the two like I have on the other-side of the `=` as well: `display_errors\s*=\s*...` (updated my answer to reflect)

Answer (score 0):

Split the text by newlines, loop over each line with a regexp like this:

```
display_errors ?= ?(On|Off)
```

Compile that with case-insensitivity to catch slight errors.  Capture the value of the first group to get the status from that match.  In each iteration of the loop, just overwrite a variable with the current status in, after the loop has ended, the variable will contain the value for the last display_errors.